# Why is my property of type int[] set to null?

Tags: c#, .net

Hopefully I've just done something dumb but I get an int array and I want to assign that to a property - but even though the int array is not null, when I assign it to the property it is null. Note this is broken into several statements as I was testing that my select statement worked ok.

```
int[] placementslist = selfSelPlacements.Select(p => p == null ? 0 : p.PlacementId).ToArray<int>();
```

I have tried

```
UnitOfferingListCriteria.Placements = new int[placementslist.Length];
```

as well as just assigning

```
UnitOfferingListCriteria.Placements = placementslist;
```

But UnitOfferingListCriteria.Placements is always null despite placementslist having 1 item.

In my class for the property

```
public int[] Placements { get; set; }
```

If someone could point out what I'm doing wrong - thanks!

Edit - thanks for the suggestions, been swamped with other stuff so haven't had a chance to get back to it yet.

Comment: Can you post a complete program that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Is your property really just `Placements { get; set; }`, or do you have actual getters and setters that you didn't post. If it's the latter, your setter is probably just broken.

Comment: Do you have any object hierearchy there? If so, it is possible that property in the base class wasn't properly overridden and is hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public int[] Placements { get; set; }
```

will have a default value of null.

Is `UnitOfferingListCriteria` a class or a class instance? It looks like you are doing something with a static property? Or are you accessing a property on a property?

Comment: Nerd, can you leave a clue about what you're thinking?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
int[] placementslist = selfSelPlacements.Select(p => p == null ? 0 : p.PlacementId).ToArray<int>();
UnitOfferingListCriteria.Placements = new int[placementslist.Length];
placementslist.CopyTo(UnitOfferingListCriteria.Placements, 0);
```

And the class

```
public class UnitOfferingListCriteria
{
    public static int[] Placements{ get; set; }
}
```

Are you doing anything different?

Answer (score 0):

The instance you are trying to reference in the property must not be null when you do it. This is obvious, but sometimes obvious is just much obvious.